# How do I change the default boot entry wih EasyBCD and skip a extra reboot.

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-8

After installing windows I installed Ubuntu with creating a separated partition to boot. Then I have added this partition with EasyBCD software, as boot options of windows. Until here I didn't have any problems.

But choosing Ubuntu now causes an extra reboot. I don't want that, please tell me how to get ride of this problem or how to choose Ubuntu as my default boot.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change the [default Boot entry](https://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd/basics/changing-default-entry/)?

Also, I don't think that using a EasyBCD would have been necessary. I'm not sure, but I think the extra reboot when you choose Ubuntu comes from that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Well let me rephrase that... Windows automatically hibernates by default when you shut down the computer (not Restart, just Shut Down). Even if you don't hibernate, it's hibernating the 'system session' for you.

So, because you installed with EasBCD, the Windows boot manager is in control, and it is aware that the drive is hibernated. So, it basically unhibernates itself which requires a restart.

You can try [disabling Fast start](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html), or you can select Restart instead of Shut down. I am not sure if this eliminates the restart, but it's worth a try. Or you can just learn to live with it. The good part is that it automatically allows you to mount the C: drive, whereas if Grub was your boot manager, you wouldn't be able to get read-write access to it while it's hibernated.